# How to encrypt / decrypt textbox1 text using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two textbox1 i want on textbox1 text changed event the textbox1 text is encrypted in textbox2 ... how to do it using vb.net ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tutorials online about how to encrypt strings in .NET.  [Here's one](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67705-rsa-encryption-in-vbnet/).  Basically, what you're looking for is in the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography`.

The real question is, what exactly do you mean when you say "text changed event"?  Right now I'm *assuming* that you're talking about entering a string into a text input form element, clicking a button to initiate the post-back, and then using that event on the post-back.  If you mean to do this *live* as the text is actually being changed then you're looking at two options:

1. Have an AJAX handler perform the encryption and return the result.  I'm not sure about the security implications here.  It may not be a big deal, but that much traffic going over the wire surrounding encryption might not be a good thing.  (Unless it's encrypted already, using SSL for example.)
2. Do the encryption in JavaScript.  There are also a number of tutorials and JavaScript libraries out there for this.  But encryption in JavaScript is generally considered dangerous ground because the client can see everything you're doing.  There's a very good chance that the encryption isn't secure at all.